# Query to get the string out of the column in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse, materialized-views

I am looking to store the MV names in to variable from a column `WHAT` which is in Table `dba_jobs`.

I want the MV Name `AP_OTHER_PERIODS_EMP_MV` to be stored in a variable so that i can use that variable as a parameter in a procedure to pass the MV name.

I tried the following but it can be used only for this specific job but I am looking for a general code which can be used in all the jobs.

`select substr(CAST(WHAT AS VARCHAR(4000)),33,23) as w from DBA_JOBS where BROKEN = 'N';`

The content in `WHAT` Col is something like this: `(dbms_refresh.refresh('"SYSTEM"."AP_OTHER_PERIODS_EMP_MV"');)`

but I only need the MV name form the column starting from "AP_".

Image contains the DBA_JOBS Table:
[image: Image contains the DBA_JOBS Table]

Comment: Can you provide a test dataset? It would be helpful to have more rows which should be taken into consideration and also few which shoudl be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. Note that `WHAT` column in `DBA_JOBS` is already `VARCHAR2(4000)`. You don't need to `CAST` it again.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(WHAT, 'dbms_refresh.refresh\(''.+\."(AP_.+)"''\)' ,1,1,'i',1)
FROM dba_jobs
WHERE BROKEN = 'N'
AND REGEXP_LIKE (WHAT,'dbms_refresh.refresh\(''.+\."AP_') ;
```